# res.render only after previous function has finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using an api to fetch an array of data which goes into a variable. It takes a while for it to fill up the array, this array is then passed to the res.render file using:

```
setTimeout(function(){ res.render("page", {searchArray: searchArray}) }, 7000);
```

Thats the last line but half the time it renders the page before the array is filled up which causes errors. The amount of time it takes to fill the array depends on the amount of elements the user chooses to search for. Is there a way to only run the render after the array is filled up without having to hardcode a random time like 7000 ?

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code, had to change the 7,000 to 20,000 because 7000 rendered the page too fast before array fill up

```
app.post("/search", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
  var searchArray;

  queryOptions = {
  query: req.body.query,
  location: req.body.city + ", " + req.body.state,
  radius: '25',
  sort: 'date',
  limit: req.body.limit
  };

  searchApi.query(queryOptions).then(res => {
    setTimeout(function(){ searchArray = res; console.log("Search array done!") }, 10);
  });

  setTimeout(function(){ res.render("SearchResults", {searchArray: searchArray}) }, 20000);
});
```

I want to avoid using settimeout to guess when the previous lines will complete its task.

Comment: what about if render the page after getting the fetch result?

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code including the asynchronous code that is filling up the array.  You should NOT be using `setTimeout()` here.  You should be using proper asynchronous callbacks or promises so you can redner when it's actually done.  We can advise you on the proper way to code it if you show us the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: Use async/await or callbacks. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: OK i added the full code, I tried reading that link using .then() but  I keep getting errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is put `render` into resolved promise. Because the `then` method is called after the query is finished.

```
  searchApi.query(queryOptions).then(searchArray => {
    res.render("SearchResults", {searchArray}) }
  });
```